# loop through all images in a div and display image with blur effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have multiple images in a div like

```
<div class="am-container" id="am-container">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg"></img></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/2.jpg"></img></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/3.jpg"></img></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/4.jpg"></img></a>
</div>
```

now i want to loop through all the images and display as blur and on mouseover it will be displayed as its original form.

can i do it with simple jquery,i have gone through few tutorials and demo with gaussian.js  blur.js but could not get it right.

please suggest.

Comment: At least show us what you have tried!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with pure CSS (will only work in Webkit browsers)

```
.am-container a img {
    filter: url(#blurred);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}

.am-container a:hover img {
    filter: url(#unblurred);
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
}
```

Add this SVG into the HTML code or reference it from an external file (to add Firefox support):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blurred" x="0" y="0">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5" />
    </filter>
    <filter id="unblurred" x="0" y="0">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w33psk9g/)</kbd>

Comment: thnks for the effort. but i want to show the initial images in blur effect and onmouseover it will reveal its original.

Comment: I have edited my answer to do that. The images will load blurred, and will unblur on hover.

Comment: i took a look on the JSFiddle but not working from my side.i am using firefox

Comment: This only works in Webkit based browsers (i.e. Chrome, Safari). Firefox does not support CSS filters. If you need firefox support you will need an SVG filter or a JS solution. I will edit my answer to add a SVG filter.

Answer (score 0):

```
.am-container a img:hover {
-webkit-filter: blur(2px);
-moz-filter: blur(2px);
filter: blur(2px);
}
```

Use this...